# Discussion on different stock footage providers

Tags: discussion

I want to ask a question here about finding stock footage websites as a seller - there's a lot of them out there and i'm not sure where to start in trying to determine the "appropriate" one.

I'm not sure if this is the site even to ask this question - but is is video related - what to do with the video after it's made, so it may be appropriate.  I'm asking this in meta as i've seen similar questions on other SE sites, which are valid questions seeking ideas on what questions one must consider - be closed.

So i'm interested in if this question belongs on Video.SE at all (or where else?), and how would I be best to phrase it to not have it closed?

I've never used the meta discussion before so please, be gentle.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think that selection of distribution channels could be considered on topic as it is part of the overall steps in producing a video.  That said, I think you would need to be careful to keep the question to talking about what to look for and avoid in a platform rather than asking about which platform to use.  What different platforms offer can change at any time so specific product recommendations would probably be a poor fit.

Additionally, be sure to scope the question well for the type of content you are trying to distribute if you want a list of generic strengths and weaknesses to look for.  The same goes for if you have some platforms in mind and want help comparing.  A lot of the strengths and weaknesses may depend on what your content is like.